# Cómo puedo exportar un fichero en formato xls?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interop

Cómo puedo exportar un fichero en formato `xls`?

Tengo un problema, cuando le cambio a `Exportación.xls` me aparece un error antes de abrir el Excel. Necesito que me exporte con extensión `xls`, o en todo caso, le cambie la extensión a `xls` antes de que abra el archivo.

Este es mi código:

```
object fileName = string.Format("Exportación.xml");
Stream fileExcel = new FileStream((String)fileName, FileMode.Create);
gridEXExporter1.ExportMode = ExportMode.AllRows;
gridEXExporter1.IncludeExcelProcessingInstruction = true;
gridEXExporter1.Export(fileExcel);
fileExcel.Close();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((string)fileName);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues la librería `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` te va a ayudar a llegar a lo que buscas

Comment: Aunque a un archivo xml (como el que creas en tu código) le cambies la extensión a xls no lo va a convertir en un archivo xls, por eso excel te marca el error, le pones xls pero no es un archivo xls. Yo antes de usar Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel buscaría alguna librería gratuita (hay varias) ya que Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel pide tener Excel en la máquina donde ejecutas tu aplicación.